# getting resized image new width and height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

On resize i need to get the new width and height of the div,
I have doing this script using jquery-ui and jquery but it fail

```
$(this).resizable(function(){
            console.log("Height: " + $(this).height());
            console.log("Width: " + $(this).width());
        });
```

help to find how to correct this error.

Comment: can't we do like dragable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).resizable()
       .on("resize", function() {
        console.log("Height: " + $(this).height());
        console.log("Width: " + $(this).width());
});
```

or

```
$(this).resizable({
  resize: function(event, ui ) {
        console.log("Height: " + ui.height());
        console.log("Width: " + ui.width());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

`$(this).on('resize',function(){
    // Your stuff goes here
});`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've been doing it:

```
 <script>
    function resizeDiv() {
        vpw = $(window).width();
        vph = $(window).height();
        console.log("Width: " + vpw);
        console.log("Height: " + vph);
    }

    window.onresize = function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have talk about resizing div not the window